# BMI Calculator in C# question about pulling previously typed data

Tags: c#, console

So I have been messing around with coding a BMI calculator from an online program, I want the final output of data to say something like: "Based on your height of 75" and weight of 200lbs your BMI is: "

I can't really figure out how to pull the data that I have already prompted the user to write back into my final sentence, I am not super experienced in coding and see this is something a lot of people start with. Any help is appreciated, I see a lot of flak for people asking these questions since it seems to be the first project in colleges.

```
 // Variables
        decimal height;
        decimal weight;
        decimal BodyMassIndex;



        Console.Write("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
        decimal lb = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter your height in inches: ");
        decimal ft = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());

        decimal BMI = lb / (ft * ft) * 703;
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI based on your height and weight is: " + Math.Round(BMI, 1));

        // exit prompt
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to concat your string (like you did for BMI value) with variables, you prompted previously:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your BMI based on your height " + ft + " and weight of " + lb + "lbs your BMI is: " + Math.Round(BMI, 1));
```

also you can use simplified syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Your BMI based on your height {ft} and weight of {lb} lbs your BMI is: {Math.Round(BMI, 1)}");
```

Comment: So in order for me to use the " next to ft value I have to use the \"  after to separate it from the WriteLine(" ")?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Based on your height of " + ft + " and weight of " + lb + "lbs your BMI is:" + Math.Round(BMI, 1));
```

So the application already read the values for **ft** and **lb** when the user entered. The compiler stores this in memory until it is cleared or until the application is terminated.